# Do I need node.js to use UglifyJs2?

Tags: node.js, uglifyjs

I'm trying to use the command line tools of UglifyJs to minify my files. On the git page it says to download it using npm: `npm install uglify-js -g`.

Is that the only way to download it? My website doesn't use node.js so I'm wondering if there's an alternate way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download it directly from it's [github repo](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS). However, I do agree with JohnnyHK it's better to install via `npm` as it will handle any dependancies required by UglifyJS.

Comment: Apologies for the beginner question but basically I can just run `git clone git://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2.git` and I'll gain access to the command line tools?

Comment: Correct, you'll be able to use it's CLI after cloning from github.

Comment: So I cloned the repo, I tried using `uglifyjs` in command line and I got `command not found`. Do I need to add it to my path?

Comment: In bash go into `bin` directory and issue the command: `./uglifyjs`

Comment: The bin directory is there. I cloned it and tested prior to answering. https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS/tree/master/bin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116003/discussion-between-jonathan-eustace-and-markscode).

Answer (score 1):

When installing a module using `npm -g`, you're installing a command-line utility that uses node.js for its run-time rather than a module for a node.js based web site.

So it's still easiest to use `npm` to install it.

Comment: I agree, npm is the way to go.